# Error Entity name 'N/A' of kind 'Database' does not exist

Tags: azure-data-explorer

I'm playing around with the Azure Date Explorer service. Am trying to follow the [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/ingest-sample-data) and create a table using:

```
.create table StormEvents (StartTime: datetime, EndTime: datetime, EpisodeId: int, EventId: int, State: string, EventType: string, InjuriesDirect: int, InjuriesIndirect: int, DeathsDirect: int, DeathsIndirect: int, DamageProperty: int, DamageCrops: int, Source: string, BeginLocation: string, EndLocation: string, BeginLat: real, BeginLon: real, EndLat: real, EndLon: real, EpisodeNarrative: string, EventNarrative: string, StormSummary: dynamic)
```

However I get the message:
    Error Entity name 'N/A' of kind 'Database' does not exist. clientRequestId: KustoWebV2;38b1da41-5827-4d55-986a-457190528f82

Answer (score 2):

The `.create table` command must run in the context of a specific database.

If you haven't yet [created a database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/create-cluster-database-portal#create-a-database), you'll need to create one first, in order to create a table.

Make sure you're "pointing" to a database you have the required permissions (`DatabaseUser` or higher) to in the connections panel on the left site of the UX, and that you're not "pointing" to the Azure Data Explorer cluster itself.

Answer (score 2):

Ok I worked it out. There appears to be a bug.

After you create a database using the Azure portal, and you click query. You will see it says error in that middle pane where the cluster is shown.

1. Go back to your cluster overview, grab the URL (i.e. https://DBNAME.YOURREGION.kusto.windows.net)
2. Go to where the error is show, click edit, then paste in the URI

It should now work. Also interestingly when you hit edit again the URL is displayed as the same short-form that you had when you had the error nut somehow pasting it in again has fixed it.

Comment: It worked for one time but later in second try it does not.

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating a table via the portal in the "Query" section, you need to make sure your scope is on the database, not on the cluster itself. Click on the `>>` button and you will see the cluster, hit refresh and click on the database underneath to select the database scope. Now execute the query again and it will work.